# iPad - How can I make my UIActionSheet look like the thin one in safari?

Tags: ipad, safari, uiactionsheet

[image]

The above UIActionSheet is thinner than the normal one. I took the screenshot from Safari when I try to bookmark some website.

Mine or the default UIActionSheet in iPad looks like the following. It is thicker than the one in Safari, especially the border.

[image]

How can I make my own UIActionSheet look like the one in Safari?
Do I need to do any particular customisation or I can use some kinds of parameters for UIActionSheet?

thanks

Comment: Use showFromBarButtonItem method as Evan says but also set title and cancel button to nil.

Comment: @aBitObvious, i don't mean where this UIActionSheet shows, I mean how can I make it thinner like the safari one, i mean the border thinner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instance method:

```
showFromBarButtonItem:animated:
```

Documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

On iPad, it will display the UIActionSheet inside a Popover.

Comment: Try removing the cancel button by setting cancelButtonTitle to nil.

Comment: Removing the title and cancel button, as shown in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/iPadHIG/UIElements/UIElements.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009446-CH6-SW9 should render the UIActionSheet full width. There is no need for a cancel button, as the user can tap outside of the popover to dismiss it.