# Safari-style UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

It is clear that UIPopoverController was not designed to be customized very much. However, is there an obvious way to mimic the UIPopoverController that is presented in mobile Safari (to add a bookmark, for example), that is, a popover with only buttons, no visible inner shadow, and an even background?

The reason for my question is because quite a few applications use a similarly styled popover, such as Reeder and Instapaper. Are these subclasses of UIPopoverController or custom UIViewControllers that mimic a UIPopoverController?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016558/ipad-how-can-i-make-my-uiactionsheet-look-like-the-thin-one-in-safari)?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. I was not aware that this is part of the API of UIActionSheet. If you submit this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks, Anna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `UIActionSheet`. Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Anna Karenina mentioned this some time ago in a comment on this question. However, it might be good for future reference that this question has an accepted answer. Thanks for your input.